# Why doesn't cp detect '\ ' (backslash+space)?

Tags: command-line, bash, regex

I was trying to write a shell script to copy files. Here is what I have done.

```
 workingDirectory=$(pwd | sed "s/ /\\ /g")
```

Now `echo $workingDirectory` shows `/home/user/Documents/Learning and Development/`.

But I know, in order for `cp` command to work I need to replace spaces with `\` (backslash+space). So I changed the `sed` command slightly as,

```
workingDirectory=$(pwd | sed "s/ /\\\ /g")
```

So that, `echo $workingDirectory` shows `/home/user/Documents/Learning\ and\ Development/`. All good.

But when try to use `cp` command as,

```
cp $workingDirectory/jad/jad /usr/bin/
```

I get errors,

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/Documents/Learning\\’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘and\\’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘Development/jad/jad’: No such file or directory
```

What could be the reason? How to resolve this?

EDIT

If I use the first `sed` command, then the errors are

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/home/user/Documents/Learning’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘and’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘Development/jad/jad’: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping a field separator inside a variable to prevent word splitting isn't useful: the shell will still split words on the separators listed in `$IFS`:

```bsh
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ workingDirectory=$(pwd | sed "s/ /\\\ /g")
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ echo $workingDirectory 
/home/user/tmp/directory\ with\ spaces
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ strace /bin/echo $workingDirectory |& grep '^execve'
execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "/home/user/tmp/directory\\", "with\\", "spaces"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
```

So an obvious workaround for that would be setting `$IFS` to an empty string (and avoiding escaping spaces at all), essentially disabling word splitting entirely:

```bsh
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ workingDirectory=$(pwd)
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ echo $workingDirectory 
/home/user/tmp/directory with spaces
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ IFS=
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ strace -s 64 /bin/echo $workingDirectory |& grep '^execve'
execve("/bin/echo", ["/bin/echo", "/home/user/tmp/directory with spaces"], [/* 62 vars */]) = 0
~/tmp/directory with spaces$ stat $workingDirectory
  File: ‘/home/user/tmp/directory with spaces’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 812h/2066d  Inode: 782086      Links: 2
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/    user)   Gid: ( 1000/    user)
Access: 2016-03-24 11:22:43.606332994 +0100
Modify: 2016-03-24 10:51:00.835689309 +0100
Change: 2016-03-24 10:51:00.835689309 +0100
 Birth: -
```

However disabling word splitting entirely in general doesn't make too much sense. Unless you have good reasons to disable word splitting entirely for more than one command I suggest you simply use double quotes to prevent it limitedly to the strings that can possibly contain field separators:

```bsh
workingDirectory=$(pwd)
cp "$workingDirectory"/jad/jad /usr/bin/
```

Comment: Special thanks for not limiting the answer by just saying to use double quotes.

Comment: When dealing with files or directories whose names contain funny characters (including SPACE), I find `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` extremely useful. Read `man find`, `man xargs`. Other NULL-terminated-string-friendly programs are `du`, `grep`, `perl`, `shuf`, `sort`, `uniq`, `xargs`, `xz`, `modinfo'.